# Cassandra modeling issues

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

First of all extremely sorry for such a long post, please bear with me.

I am new to cassandra and need someone to review my data models. My objective is to model a database for social media post table. I am planning to have following two tables to store and fetch posts efficiently.

1. post table
2. posts_by_user table

All posts will be stored in first table i,e post, here is the structure

`CREATE TABLE myapp_keyspace.posts (
    id timeuuid,
    createdat bigint,
    city text,
    topFourComments list<frozen<comment>>,
    commentscount bigint,
    content text,
    contenttype text,
    country text,
    county text,
    createdon bigint,
    deletedon bigint,
    iscreator boolean,
    isdeleted boolean,
    likescount bigint, 
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    medias list<frozen<media>>,
    mediatype text,
    postcreatedby timeuuid,
    posttype text,
    postusername text,
    postuserprofilepic text,
    sharecount bigint,
    state text,
    status int,
    tags list<frozen<tag>>,
    timezone text,
    title text,
    updatedon bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, createdat))`

Below is a different table where data is getting duplicated for timeline screen. Timeline screen also has following filters (All, Image, Video, Text, Friends, Group), here is the structure.

`CREATE TABLE myapp_keyspace .posts_by_user (
    postcreatedby timeuuid,
    contenttype text,
    mediatype text,
    posttype text,
    createdat bigint,
    comments list<frozen<comment>>,
    commentscount bigint,
    content text,
    createdon bigint,
    deletedon bigint,
    id timeuuid,
    iscreator boolean,
    isdeleted boolean,
    likescount bigint,
    medias list<frozen<media>>,
    sharecount bigint,
    status int,
    tags list<frozen<tag>>,
    title text,
    updatedon bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (postcreatedby, contenttype, mediatype, posttype, createdat)`

Following are my two questions

 1. As cassandra says plan a separate table for each query. Considering all filters on timeline screen, is it good to write single query for all filters or should I plan to write separate for each filter. (All, image, video, text, friends, group)

 2. What should I plan for storing friend's posts. I am thinking of duplicating all friend's posts in post_by_user table. Ex: If I have 10 friends and I am making a post. So single post will be stored 10 times, one for each friend in the posts_by_user table.

Since this is my first project in cassandra and I want to be extra cautious in designing the database to avoid any issues in future.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Data modeling in Cassandra is tough. Don't feel bad **at all** about struggling with it, especially at first. One thing that's worked well for me, and is quite different from other databases (especially SQL), is to write out queries first, not tables. With Cassandra, the `select` statements are where the trouble will be.

I'd suggest you actually write out every `select` you'll need, keeping in mind what information you'll have to do the query. This is critical, because it will dictate how you form your primary keys. An additional, and important feature is [compound keys](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompoundPrimaryKey.html). This is helpful for sorting results, and it might be relevant for your situation.

For your first table, are you sure you want both a `id` and `createdat`? The creation time can be derived from the `timeuuid` type. Or, perhaps you need a more fine-grained time? Think about this, because you'll need both to query the table.

Your `posts_by_user` table, as you've guessed, is where the real issues are. Think of your keys from left to right. So for your `posts_by_user`, if you want to leave `createdat` wildcard, you must restrict all preceding columns. I doubt this is what you'd like to do. You cannot restrict just `mediatype`, for example.

Arbitrary filtering like this might be difficult to do in Cassandra. Consider what your UI/Application needs. This is why modeling your queries first, instead of tables, is so useful.

Hopefully this is helpful - and good luck!

Comment: Thanks Matt, We are little confused on 2nd point. My simple query is good enough to get data from single table for all filters. If I go with that I need to create about 5 fields as primary key. My worry is about the complexity, is it good practice to have such keys?

Comment: It's very common to have long, complex keys. Your primary key structure is the only way to support queries, so it makes sense that it will involve all the fields your query involves. Most of your design effort goes into the structure of primary keys, in my experience.